# Is it permissible for a woman to pray during her menses?

Tags: women, worship, menses

I will like to give an answer to someone who asked me this question, I looked all over but I could not find anything that actually states that women should not worship during this time, or stating that it is Haraam.  My question is - is it okay for a women to worship during her menses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule of prayer for women menses is haraam,and not permissible a prayer or fasting or Tawaaf around the House and touch Holy Quran ...

> حَدَّثَنَا ابْنُ أَبِي مَرْيَمَ، حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ جَعْفَرٍ،
>   قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي زَيْدٌ، عَنْ عِيَاضٍ، عَنْ أَبِي سَعِيدٍ ـ رضى الله
>   عنه ـ قَالَ قَالَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ أَلَيْسَ إِذَا
>   حَاضَتْ لَمْ تُصَلِّ، وَلَمْ تَصُمْ فَذَلِكَ نُقْصَانُ دِينِهَا ‏"‏‏
>
> Narrated Abu Sa`id: The Prophet said, "Isn't it true that a woman does
>   not pray and does not fast on menstruating? And that is the defect (a
>   loss) in her religion."
>
> [Sahih al-Bukhari]

and she do not spend a missed prayer   during the period of menstrual, but she spend that she has missed fasting.

> قَالَتْ سَأَلْتُ عَائِشَةَ فَقُلْتُ مَا بَالُ الْحَائِضِ تَقْضِي
>   الصَّوْمَ وَلاَ تَقْضِي الصَّلاَةَ فَقَالَتْ أَحَرُورِيَّةٌ أَنْتِ
>   قُلْتُ لَسْتُ بِحَرُورِيَّةٍ وَلَكِنِّي أَسْأَلُ ‏.‏ قَالَتْ كَانَ
>   يُصِيبُنَا ذَلِكَ فَنُؤْمَرُ بِقَضَاءِ الصَّوْمِ وَلاَ نُؤْمَرُ
>   بِقَضَاءِ الصَّلاَةِ
>
> Mu'adha said: I asked 'A'isha: What is the reason that a menstruating
>   woman completes the fasts (that she abandons during her monthly
>   course). but she does not complete the prayers? She (Hadrat 'A'isha)
>   said: Are you a Haruriya? I said: I am not a Haruriya, but I simply
>   want to inquire. She said: We passed through this (period of
>   menstruation), and we were ordered to complete the fasts, but were not
>   ordered to complete the prayers.

[Sahih Muslim ]

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not OK and even haraam to worship during menses. There are about 20 ruling regarding menses, some of the important one are below

**1. Praying is haraam and waived**. That includes both obligatory and nawafil. If a woman does it, they are not valid. She is not required to make up these prayers.

**2. Fasting is haraam that is both obligatory and nawafil.** If she fasts, it is not accepted. But she has to make up the obligatory fasts that she missed.

**3. Tawaaf around the Kaabah is haraam (obligatory and naafil)**. She *must* make up for the obligatory tawaaf though when she becomes pure.

> The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said to
>   ‘Aa’ishah when she got her menses: “Do everything that the pilgrims
>   do, but do not circumambulate the House until you become pure.”

**4. Tawaaf (Fairwell) around kabah during hajj haraam and waived**. She does not need to make it up. She can simply leave the Hajj without performing the farewell tawaaf.

**5. Staying in the mosque is haraam even on eid Prayer**. This comes from

> Hadeeth of Umm ‘Atiyyah (may Allaah be pleased with her), who said
>   that she heard the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)
>   say: “Let the girls who have attained puberty, women in seclusion and
>   menstruating women go out – i.e., to the Eid prayer.” In this hadeeth
>   it says: “But let the menstruating women avoid the prayer place.”

[Source of information](http://www.islam-qa.com/en/ref/70438/praying%20menstruation)

Comment: @Ahmadi I removed point 6 and 7. Were included just as extra info. But you are right answer should be to the point. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

according to shia Islam woman should not do daily prayers. but by leaving prayers, woman will lose her spiritual state and so it is recommended woman sit in her everyday prayer place and recite some Zikr other than prayer. especially Tasbih of Bibi Fateme Zehra (a.s) is highly recommended for this case:

[Tasbih of Bibi Fateme Zehra (a.s)](http://www.duas.org/tasbihzehra.htm)